# Mails marked as spam from Google - SPF and DKIM passes

Tags: email, gmail, spam, spf, dkim

I am going crazy to figure out why my emails are being marked as spam by Gmail.

SPF and DKIM all pass.

Any idea what could be going on? Here is an example header from Gmail (IPs and domains changed for privacy):

```
Delivered-To: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com
Received: by 10.50.15.201 with SMTP id z9csp2075257igc;
        Wed, 21 Jan 2015 12:34:45 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.180.89.225 with SMTP id br1mr37591618wib.70.1421872484313;
        Wed, 21 Jan 2015 12:34:44 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <yyyyyy@example.com>
Received: from MY.MAILSERVER.com (MY.MAILSERVER.com. [217.172.XXX.XXX])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id k10si315060wiz.77.2015.01.21.12.34.43
        for <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com>
        (version=TLSv1.1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 21 Jan 2015 12:34:44 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of yyyyyy@example.com designates 217.172.XXX.XXX as permitted sender) client-ip=217.172.XXX.XXX;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of yyyyyy@example.com designates 217.172.XXX.XXX as permitted sender) smtp.mail=yyyyyy@example.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@example.com
Received: from PietPC (ip-84-119-117-236.unity-media.net [84.119.117.236])
    (using TLSv1 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA (256/256 bits))
    (No client certificate requested)
    (Authenticated sender: yyyyyy@example.com)
    by MY.MAILSERVER.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 1A56F7659B3
    for <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com>; Wed, 21 Jan 2015 21:34:31 +0100 (CET)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=example.com; s=mail;
    t=1421872486; bh=PwUG0SLiX8we/Zb4/tKUkTAw+2s5Aab+YjM1uaM2FOY=;
    h=From:To:Subject:Date;
    b=FbGkEinlkILGtwi5DI9zJXN2wTIUhGMvhI34pwWiyXIZMBUkNX+4EahcTkNwSIWdS
     epSqWBjjQ33j5D33jVylRBSka4eyNH7aCZJLH91iWLD5G09OEGeCCgeq7Rf7pQ5PC5
     ry/6Eq72t7jqxEoxINVnY8odfQx8BPQ19qNTuHIA=
From: <yyyyyy@example.com>
To: <XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@gmail.com>
Subject: Mittag Essen
Date: Wed, 21 Jan 2015 21:34:20 +0100
Message-ID: <012b01d035b9$ab92f060$02b8d120$@example.com>
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook 14.0
Thread-Index: AdA1uaJS4CMjPIuyTaimdKHtOrYSoQ==
Content-Language: de

Besteht unser Termin fuers Mittag essen?
```

Comment: This is not the best site to ask this kind of questions on. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: Passing SPF and DKIM is not enough to ensure than a message is not marked as spam.  Traditionally SPF and DKIM have played a somewhat minimal role in spam categorization.  Adding a DMARC record may boost their contribution, but that's not a sure thing.